# Removing labels in scikit-image

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have labeled an binary image
[image]

```
imageLabels = morphology.label(imageBinary, background=255)
```

However when I check the number of labels, I get 535 elements.

```
print(len(imageLabels))
```

As a solution for this I thought about using `measure.regionprops` in order to remove the labels with a small pixel area. How would you guys approach this? I have tried the following, but for one reason or another the new array is no longer seen as a correct label element.

```python
i=0
for labelprop in measure.regionprops(imageLabels):
    if (labelprop.area > 100):
        imageLabels_keep.append(imageLabels[i])
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `morphology.remove_small_objects(image, min_px_size)` does what you're looking for. Here's an example that uses that function:

http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_coins_segmentation.html#edge-based-segmentation