# scikit-image - felzenszwalb segmentation: remove large segments

Tags: numpy, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I'm using `skimage.segmentation.felzenszwalb` as shown [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_segmentations.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-segmentations-py), and it's great.

I've tuned the parameters as best as I can, but it's still detecting some large segments I don't want it to. How can I remove segments above a certain size afterwards? I know you can use `skimage.measure.regionprops` to get the area of each segment, but i'm not sure how to then remove a segment from `segments_fz`, leaving the array in tact for `mark_boundaries`.

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
from skimage.util import img_as_float
from skimage.segmentation import felzenszwalb
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries

img = img_as_float(astronaut()[::2, ::2])
segments_fz = felzenszwalb(img, scale=100, sigma=0.5, min_size=50)

print("Felzenszwalb number of segments: {}".format(len(np.unique(segments_fz))))

segmented_img = mark_boundaries(img, segments_fz)
skimage.io.imsave('img_labeled.png', segmented_img)
```

This is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584178/removing-labels-in-scikit-image), but they are trying to remove small objects, instead of large ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/b710bd21d2b962409a4edf173b123a90d3c7daa0/skimage/morphology/misc.py#L47) for `skimage.morphology.remove_small_objects`. There's a lot of pre-processing / input cleaning, but the business end is quite simple. Assuming `segments` is your input image with segment labels, here's what the function is doing:

```
out = np.copy(segments)
component_sizes = np.bincount(segments.ravel())
too_small = component_sizes < min_size
too_small_mask = too_small[segments]
out[too_small_mask] = 0
return out
```

You can change `too_small` to `too_big`, or really any condition you want! The key is to produce an array at that line that contains `True` at position i whenever you want to zero out label i, and `False` everywhere else.